# ggplot2's geom_contour versus geom_density_2d. Is there any difference?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can successfully use [`ggplot2`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/index.html)'s [`geom_contour`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_contour.html) and [`geom_density_2d`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_density_2d.html).

However, I cannot tell any real ***difference*** between the two, except for ***minor*** differences in syntax.

---

#### Does anyone out there know what real difference - if any - there is between the two?

---

I have already looked at the documentation, as well as examples outside of the documentation.  This is why I provided links to the documentation, so that those of you wishing to help do not simply point me to the documentation.

Thanks!